# Add a new row with data in Sheets when using LOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have some data in a sheet I'd like to lookup, but I'm wondering if there's a way to not only get this information from columns A and B using a lookup function, but to also add a row after 1, 2, 3, etc.

So my information goes from this:

```
Fake task 1     0.78125
Fake task 2     0.9375
Fake task 3     1.09375
Fake task 4     1.25
Fake task 5     1.40625
Fake task 6     1.5625
Fake task 7     1.71875
Fake task 8     1.875
Fake task 9     2.03125
Fake task 10    2.1875
Fake task 11    2.34375
Fake task 12    2.5
Fake task 13    2.65625
Fake task 14    2.8125
Fake task 15    2.96875
Fake task 16    3.125
Fake task 17    3.28125
Fake task 18    3.4375
Fake task 19    3.59375
Fake task 20    3.8612
```

to this:

```
Sprint 1
Fake task 1     0.78125
Fake task 2     0.9375

Sprint 2
Fake task 3     1.09375
Fake task 4     1.25
Fake task 5     1.40625
Fake task 6     1.5625
Fake task 7     1.71875
Fake task 8     1.875

Sprint 3
Fake task 9     2.03125
Fake task 10    2.1875
Fake task 11    2.34375
Fake task 12    2.5
Fake task 13    2.65625
Fake task 14    2.8125
Fake task 15    2.96875

Sprint 4
Fake task 16    3.125
Fake task 17    3.28125
Fake task 18    3.4375
Fake task 19    3.59375
Fake task 20    3.8612
```

Updated to add my table of sprints:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", )&" "&REGEXREPLACE(COUNTIFS(
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ),
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ), 
 ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D))&"", "^0$", )&
 "♦"&A2:A&"♠"&B2:B, ),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"), "♥", ), "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", )&" "&REGEXREPLACE(COUNTIFS(
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ),
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))&"", "^0$", )&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", )&" "&REGEXREPLACE(COUNTIFS(
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ),
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))&"", "^0$", ), ), {"♦♥♦"&
 G3:G, "♠"&TEXT(H3:H, "dd/mm/yyyy")}, 2, 0))&
 "♦"&A2:A&"♠"&B2:B, ),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"), "♥", ), "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", )&" "&REGEXREPLACE(COUNTIFS(
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ),
 IF(COUNTIFS(IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), IF(A2:A<>"", ROUNDDOWN(B2:B), ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, "♦♥♦Sprint", ), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))&"", "^0$", ), ), {"♦♥♦"&
 G3:G, "♦♥♦♠"&H3:H}, 2, 0))&
 "♦"&A2:A&"♠"&B2:B, ),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"), "♥", ), "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Any ideas how to make Sprint 1, Sprint 2 etc. be fed from a two columned table of Sprint 1 | "date-date", Sprint 2 | "date-date", which is already populated?

Comment: Or to combine where I'm using this information in an =ARRAYFORMULA(E2:E) with something like VLOOKUP?

Comment: Cheers, can it actually override the field with 'Sprint 1' in?

Comment: Updated to include my table.

Comment: It's a text concat of two dates, so no need for dd-mm-yyyy etc.

Comment: Here's an example sheet! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nHc0eazjwh7lSIbVVjcKjBXa4W8Yi8ItebmLjxohYlU/edit#gid=1317729691

Comment: This has replaced the estimates field with the cumulative velocity too...

Comment: Are you able to show me how to add this to the sheet here? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nHc0eazjwh7lSIbVVjcKjBXa4W8Yi8ItebmLjxohYlU/edit#gid=1317729691 @player0